# Find the vector and Cartesian equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Line passing through 
$(1,0,5)$ and is perpendicular to the line $\frac{x+2}{3} = \frac{y-2}{4} = \frac{z+3}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The sufficient and necessary conditions that two lines: $$L_1 :\frac{x-x_1}{a}=\frac{y-y_1}{b}=\frac{z-z_1}{c}$$ $$L_2: \frac{x-x_2}{a'}=\frac{y-y_2}{b'}=\frac{z-z_2}{c'}$$ are perpendicular is that $aa'+bb'+cc'=0$  so you can find $a',b',c'$ just by guessing. For example if $a'=2,b'=1,c'=-2$ we have $2*3+1*4+(-2)*5=0$ so the parametric equation of one prependicular line passing through $(1,0,5)$ would be $$\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y }{1}=\frac{z-5}{-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think, there are countless answer. 
The given line has a direction vector $u=(3,4,5)$. Put $v=(a,b,c)$ be a direction vector of the needing line. We have 
$$3a + 4b+5c=0.$$
We see that, $(-2, -1, 2$, $(-3, 1, 1)$, $(-5, 5, -1)$, $(-2, 4, -2)$, $(-1, 2, -1)$, ... are  roots of this equation. That's mean, the equation  $$3a + 4b+5c=0$$ has countless solutions. Therefore there are  countless answers.

Comment: Please explain.